# What is the efficiency of step-up DC-DC "MT3608" at Vin = 2V?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, efficiency

I would like to know: "What is the efficiency of step-up DC-DC ["MT3608"](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Breadboarding/BB-PWR-3608/resources/MT3608.pdf) at Vin = 2V ?"
(E.g. at Vout = 18V , Iout = 200 mA , to be comparable to the curve in the Datasheet)
The datasheet just shows down to Vin = 3V, not down to 2V.
Has anyone measured ?
Could anyone measure please? If so, I would be interested in Vin = 2V, Vout = 14V, Iout = 0.3A

Thanks!

Comment: What that data sheet is telling you is "we don't want you to think about what happens for operation below 3V".  The fundamental rule of datasheets is that if the part doesn't perform well in a certain way, **they won't tell you** -- that fact will just be apparent in the absence of information on the datasheet.  You should find a part that _does_ boost from 2V to 18V, or you should find a part that efficiently boosts from 2V to 5V or 6V, and then boost that intermediate voltage to 18V either with the MT3608 or with some other part.

Comment: BTW: any switchers that will work with sub-3V inputs are getting into a specialty arena because it's hard to build FETs that will work at such low gate voltages.  There's not a lot of them that can efficiently go up to 18V, and I would expect that at least some that do would have an external pin to the gate driver so that once it's boosting the gate gets more drive, to _really_ fully turn the FET on.

Comment: It probably won't even be able to provide 200mA @18V with a 4A peak switch current, 150ohm worst case switch resistance and 1.98V under voltage lockout voltage.

Answer (score 3):

I tested a popular [module](http://www.icstation.com/icstation-mt3608-step-converter-module-boost-converter-power-supply-module-icsa004a-p-3448.html) that uses the MT3608.

[image]

With 7 V in I adjusted the output for 18.0 V with a 90 Ω load resistance (drawing 200 mA). Then I turned the input voltage down until it lost regulation and the output voltage started to drop.

With 2.75 V in it drew 1.70 A and produced 17.7 V at the output. This equates to 197 mA load current and 74.4% efficiency, which is actually pretty good for such a low input voltage.

At 2.0 V it drew 1.67 A from the power supply and produced 12.6 V, equating to 140 mA load current and 52.8% efficiency. This is not good. If I disconnected the power and reapplied 2.0 V it produced an unstable output for a few seconds before settling down with an output ripple of ~200 mV peak to peak.

This suggests the 3 V minimum operating voltage shown in the datasheet is realistic. It can work on 2 V, but not very well.

> I would be interested in Vin = 2V, Vout = 14V, Iout = 0.3A

I didn't try this because it couldn't even produce 14 V at 0.16 A (90 Ω load).

Comment: Dear Bruce, thank you VERY much for measuring. That's exactly what I wanted to know, if the chip can handle 2V at all, because, as aleady correctly said, the datasheet didn't tell me, but I was nevertheless interested. But if the chip becomes "unstable" at Vin=2.0 V for even seconds, I have to increase the number of NiMh cells from 2 to 3.

Comment: Or, does anyone know a complete module which can handle the following requirements with good efficiency: Vin=2.0V, Vout=5...14V, Iout= ca. 300mA @ 13V (it's a small12V fan).

Comment: Even if you find a converter with good efficiency at 2V,  the battery current will be ~2A at 2.4V. Which NiMH cells do you intend to use, and how long do you want the fan to run for?

Comment: A common approach at very low Vin is to use a converter IC that has a separate Vsupply, and bootstrap the Vsupply by operating it from Vout once the converter starts.

Comment: Dear Bruce, The time where the fan runs at "high power" I intended to just run for some min. then, it should run for longer time at e.g. 7V where it consumes much less power.
Dear ATCSVOL, Thank you for the interesting hint!